# Controlling collection serialization

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I am working a project where I need to serialize a collection of enums using datacontract serialization. 
The expected result should look like the following

```
<Filters>
   <MemberType>1</MemberType>
   <MemberType>2</MemberType>
   <MemberType>3</MemberType>
</Filters>
```

Here's the class that is to be serialized:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Filters")]
public class Filters
{
    private ObservableCollection<Nullable<MemberTypeEnum>>  m_enmMemberType;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "MemberType", Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ObservableCollection<Nullable<MemberTypeEnum>> MemberType
    {
        get
        {
            return m_enmMemberType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_enmMemberType != value)
            {
                m_enmMemberType = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MemberType");
            }
        }
    } 
}

[DataContract(Name = "MemberTypeEnum")]
public enum MemberTypeEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value="1")]
    [XmlEnum(Name="1")]
    T_1 = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value="2")]
    [XmlEnum(Name="2")]
    T_2 = 2,
    [EnumMember(Value="3")]
    [XmlEnum(Name="3")]
    T_3 = 3,
}
```

The problem I have is that the result I get is slightly different:

```
<Filters>
   <MemberType>
        <MemberTypeEnum>1</MemberTypeEnum>
        <MemberTypeEnum>2</MemberTypeEnum>
        <MemberTypeEnum>3</MemberTypeEnum>
   </MemberType>
</Filters>
```

Is there a way to modify the serialization (or am I doing something wrong) so that I can get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit more research and I have found another question that seems related to mine:

[CollectionDataContract serialization not adding custom properties (DataMember)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501526/collectiondatacontract-serialization-not-adding-custom-properties-datamember)

The answer with most upvotes seems to suggest that

> "This is not possible with the DataContractSerializer (DCS). The DCS
>   doesn't allow unwrapped collection elements"

I suppose I need to accept this and contact the web service provider to find out if it's possible to modify the contracts.